# transaction parameter value with Wei is different from Metamask

Tags: web3js, transactions, nft, wei

For example, I set a `tParam` as

```
value: web3.utils.toWei('0.01','ether'),
```

...

```
const txHash = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: "eth_sendTransaction",
      params: [tParam],
    });
```

It should show 0.01 ETH in Metamask, but showing 1.xx.

Where can be the problem point?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the `value` should be string hex.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction parameter value with Wei is different from Metamask, then the transaction will not be processed. You will need to double check the parameter value with Wei and make sure it is the same as the one you entered in Metamask.